# Shortest path with even number of edges

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a weighted undirected graph G and two nodes U,V to get the shortest path. How can i get the shortest path from U to V that uses a even number of edges (if possible to get it) ?

I've found some articles on the web speaking that a modification on the original graph is necessary. But i can't understand how to do it.

There is some good material to study on this problem ?

Comment: This question would fit better in computer science stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to build an intermediate graph and run Dijkstra's on that graph.

Given a graph `G = (V, E)`, create a new graph `G' = (V', E')`, with `V'` a new set of vertices `v_even` and `v_odd` for every vertex `v` in `V` and `E'` the set of vertices as follows:
If `(u, v)` is an edge in `G`, then `(u_odd, v_even)` and `(u_even, v_odd)` are edges in `G'`, with the same weight.

Obviously, the new graph has twice as many edges and vertices as the original graph.

Now, if you wanted to find the shortest path between `s` and `t` in `G`, simply run Dijkstra's on `G'` to find the shortest path between `s_even` and `t_even`.

The running time is still `O(|V| log |E|)`.

Comment: This will give you the shortest even walk, not the shortest even path. Although what you find using Dijkstra's algorithm is a path, when you merge back the "twin" edges, it could become a trail or even a walk. As a counterexample, take the graph obtained from the disjoint union of a triangle and a path of length 3, and then identifying a vertex of triangle with an internal vertex of the path.

Comment: @Untitled if I understand your argument correctly: my approach is incorrect because one way to turn an odd-length walk into an even-length walk is by making a full round on an odd-length cycle. You're right, that's a valid counter example that this approach doesn't work in general.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a copy of your graph with the same weights and call it G'.
2. Connect every vertex of G to the corresponding vertex in G' and set the weight of the new edges to zero.
3. Delete copy of u from G' and delete v from G.
4. Now, the set of edges you added between G and G' constitute a matching M. Take that matching and find a minimum augmenting path for that matching.

Such a path must have u as one of its end points and copy of v as the other endpoint, because they are the only uncovered vertices. If you merge back the copies and get rid of the added edges, the path you found corresponds to an even path, because it starts at one copy and ends at another. Also, every even path corresponds to an augmenting path (by same argument), therefore the minimum of one is also the minimum of the other. This is explained in [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230140403/full).

Comment: Can you  please post link to freely accessible paper?

Comment: @LukaRahne Sorry Luka. I couldn't find one. I guess if you request the authors they would grant you access. Maybe try requesting them through the ResearchGate page of this paper.

Answer (score 0):

What about running Dijkstra where each node has two values. One is odd (coming from even value) and other is even value.

Comment: Dijkstra's is a greedy algorithm. You cannot store both values in the same node because it will be visited just once and the even value might be very different from the odd value.

Comment: Other way around is to build a new graph with two types of nodes where it holds that each odd node points to even node and vice versa. This way one doesn’t modify Dijkstra (i I was thinking) but graph.

Comment: This will give you a walk, not a path. Please see my comment on Vincent's answer.

Comment: Yes. See my answer.